Python script for transferring groups along with their projects from one gitlab instance to other
I want to transfer groups along with the projects inside them from one gitlab instance to other.I know there isn't any direct way and I'll have to write a script for that.
I am transferring all the groups first and then downloding projects corresponding to the groups and then exporting those projects from my local to the destination gitlab.
Is there any better way ?
